# Determining if a context-free grammar produces even-length strings

Tags: computability, context-free, formal-grammars, undecidability

Given a context-free grammar, is there an algorithm to determine if the CFG will ever produce an even length string? Or is this undecidable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course there is a meta-algorithm via automata and intersection constructions. Here is an algorithm that works out of the box, no tools needed.

We mark any variable in the grammar as "even" and/or "odd". Variables can have either no, one or zero marks. For simplicity we assume the grammar is in Chomsky normal form, but the trick can be reformulated for general grammars.

- For any $A\to a$ mark $A$ as "odd"

Repeat as long as variables get new marks:

- For $A\to BC$, if $B$ and $C$ are marked, carry the mark over to $A$ according to parity ("odd"+"odd"="even", etc.)

Yes, I know that is an implementation of "CFG emptiness" and "intersection with even length strings" merged, but still I like it.

Comment: Then, I would determine if the grammar produces an even string if S is ever marked even. Because a variable can be marked as both even or odd at different times.

Answer (score 2):

There is an algorithm:

Recall that given a CFL $L$ and a regular language $K$, the language $L\cap K$ is also CFL (and a CFG for it is computable given a CFG for $L$ and a DFA for $K$).

Now, observe that the language $K=\{w: |w| \text{ is even}\}$ is regular.

From this we conclude that given a CFG $G$, we can construct a CFG for the language $\{w: |w|\text{ is even and }w\in L(G)\}$, and we observe that this language is nonempty iff $G$ generates a word of even length.

Since checking emptiness of CFG can be done in polynomial time, we can solve the problem in polynomial time.

Comment: Regarding polynomial total time, it should be noted that intersecting $L$ and $K$ is also possible in that time. Do we need a DFA for that step?

Comment: Note that $K$ here is constant, so we don't really need the DFA, as the construction is fixed. We also don't *really* need the fact that the runtime is polynomial, but rather that is is polynomial in $L$. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

1. The language of all even-length strings is regular, and you can construct a DFA that recognizes it.
2. The intersection of a regular language and a context-free language is context-free, and you can construct a CFG for it.
3. Given a CFG, it's decidable whether the language it generates is empty.
4. The language from (2) is empty as in (3) iff your context-free language generates no even-length strings.

See [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-free_language) for details.